# Reading from a java.nio.MappedByteBuffer when a FileOutputStream is open for the mapped file causes an "unsafe memory access" error

Tags: java, operating-system, nio, mmap, bytebuffer

While debugging an issue at work, I noticed that attempting to use a MappedByteBuffer after opening a FileOutputStream to the mapped file (the file from which the MappedByteBuffer was created via a call to FileChannel.map()) consistently causes the following exception to be thrown:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: a fault occurred in an unsafe memory access operation".

Here's a small code sample I threw together that consistently triggers the exception:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class SomeClass {
    // make sure the test file is at least this size, or you'll get a "cannot 
    // extend file to required size" exception when creating the buffer
    private static int bufferSize = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("/tmp/someFile");

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ByteBuffer bb = getByteBuffer(fis);

        // If you comment this out, the error goes away.
        new FileOutputStream(file);

        bb.get();
    }

    private static ByteBuffer getByteBuffer(FileInputStream fis) throws Exception {
        return fis.getChannel().map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY,
            fis.getChannel().position(), bufferSize);
    }
}
```

The above code consistently causes the aforementioned exception to be thrown. The failure happens on the "bb.get()" command and does not happen if I comment out the code that opens up the FileOutputStream.

It seems to me that the error is happening because the ByteBuffer that I'm calling .get() on is memory-mapped to the same file that I passed to the FileOutputStream. I'm guessing that there is some internal safeguard that prevents memory-mapped files from being read if the file is opened, but I'm unable to figure out what the reason is for this.

What is special about memory-mapped ByteBuffers that prevents a read operation from being allowed when an open FileOutputStream exists on the file? I'm very interested in understanding the internals of this exception. What also mystifies me is that there doesn't seem to be a similar problem opening a FileInputStream and reading from it when a FileOutputStream is open for the same file, even though this should essentially be very functionally similar (reading from a file that is already opened for writing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a memory mapping you are mapping a region of a file into memory.

When you use FileOutputStream, you truncate the file and the region of memory you mapped no longer exists.

If you don't truncate the file it will have the size you gave it when you performed the mapping.

Comment: You're absolutely right - this is definitely what's happening. I did another quick test where I passed the "append" flag to the FileOutputStream and the issue no longer occurs.